# Is there such a thing a 3 possible in Spades?

Tags: bidding, spades

We were playing Spades.  My new girlfriend said she had 2 and 3 possible.  I laughed and asked what she meant by the 3 possible.  We stopped the game to figure this out.

- Spades: 4,6
- Hearts: K,2,3,5
- Clubs: K,7
- Diamonds: K,9,8

How she should have bid?

In the end she only took 2. After knowing that, how she should have bid?

is a 3 a legit bid with this hand?

Answer (score 4):

The possible trick winners of this hand are the three Kings and the short ♣'s which allows a 3rd trick ruff/cut.

Having only two spades is a weakness. It means that there is a higher probability an opponent has a long ♠ suit.

The game of Spades encourage conservative bids since an overtrick (bag) results in a smaller loss compared to an undertrick.

I would bid 2 with this hand almost always.  If I am at the 4th sit and the sum of bidding is 7 before my bid, I would bid 3. (probably when someone bids nil)

To answer the question of the headline, in the bidding phase each player must say a single number between 0 and 13, nothing more.  She can't say: "2 and maybe 3". Of course that in a game among friends she can say whatever.

Comment: There are a lot of "in between" bids where I come from!

Comment: @TheChaz2.0, What do you mean? can you bid: 2.5?  how the scoring goes if you get the lower/higher bid?

Comment: Table talk, not actual bids.